# Git: Output the currently tracked branch name without the remote name on it

Tags: git, bash, version-control

I'm working on a git alias to perform a `git push --force`-like command in a repository where you can't push force, but you can delete remote branches. So which has this two steps:

1. delete the remote branch
2. push the local branch against to the remote

The script must work in the case of the local branch and the remote branch have different names. There is only one remote (origin) so it can be hardcoded. The alias is to be run in a bash shell only.

I'm getting stuck in getting the right upstream branch name. I know that I can get the upstream tracked branch on git with the command:

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}`

However that returns the name of the branch with the format `<remote_name>/<branch_name>` e.g: *origin/my_working_branch*

and would make the push fail as it would issue the following commands:

```
# this fails as the branch origin/my_working_branch does not exist
git push origin :origin/my_working_branch

# this will create a branch named 'origin/my_working_branch' in the remote, which is not what I want
git push origin my_working_branch:origin/my_working_branch
```

Is there any way to make `git rev-parse` to output the name of the branch without the remote/ part?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your goal to get whoever felt there was reason to prevent force pushes to also strip the ability to delete branches? Because were I in the shoes of your repo's admin, that's *exactly* what I would do if someone started doing what you're describing...

Comment: Is just a legacy default configuration for the repositories and only allowed in working branches. That probably will change. What I want is to keep the history clean while working on the branch and before creating a code review, so up to that point I can rebase from the upstream instead of being forced to merge. Of course, the moment the branch is public, I would never push force it, and master branch is protected, just in case somebody would be tempted to do the same there (o__O )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to make `git rev-parse` to output the name of the branch without the remote/ part?

No, but you don't need to.  You want to know what the name of the branch is *on the upstream*, and that's the second half of the two-part thing that `git rev-parse` works with.

That is, for branch *B*, the upstream is set in two parts: `branch.B.remote` is the name of the remote, and `branch.B.merge` is the name of the branch *on* the remote.  So if `my_working_branch` has `origin/badbranch` as its upstream, *and* everything else is the way it normally is, then:

```
git config --get branch.my_working_branch.remote
```

will output `origin`, and:

```
git config --get branch.my_working_branch.merge
```

will output the string you want: `refs/heads/badbranch`.

Note that one or both of these may be *un*-set, in which case there is no defined upstream; and if `branch.B.remote` is a literal dot `.` character, the upstream is your own repository.

(It's a good idea to use the fully-qualified `refs/heads/branch` format when deleting and re-creating a branch.  Also, be sure whoever controls the upstream won't complain that you're sidestepping the anti-force provisions. :-) )

Comment: Thanks, and don't worry, I'm just automating what I been doing manually for some months :)